# Закрученный вывод данных из таблицы

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Скажем, что имеется таблица("Оценочная ведомость"), в которой каждому id-номеру студента принадлежит id-номер предмета и соответствующая оценка. То есть по сути все id-номера повторяются, для 1-го студента будет несколько предметов и оценки по ним.

Но вывод данных должен выглядеть в виде таблицы, где строками выводятся студенты (без повторений), а столбцами будут предметы (тоже без повторений), на пересечении должны быть соответствующие оценки. Скрин приблизительно того что получилось:

[image]

Но как видно из скрина, у меня повторяются записи студентов, а переход на обработку остальных ниже идущих записей вообще не идет. Предметы вообще вывожу из другой таблицы.
Если честно, вообще не приложу ума, как такое сделать. Может это глупо, но получается, что я хочу одно значение записи вывести в строку, другое в столбец, а третье в их пересечение....

Может есть другие пути решения?

Comment: скрина не видно, просит авторизацию на том сайте, перезалейте, а мы посмотрим

Comment: перезалил)))

Comment: ваш запрос можно увидеть?

Comment: извиняюсь.но запроса уже нет.работал на денвере...со злости потом удалил файл(((.но мне не обязательно код нужен.можно просто словами объяснить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял вы держите все в одной таблице, конечно, это неправильно с одной стороны, ну да ладно.

Я бы разделил информацию по полочкам (то есть не хранил бы все в одной таблице), и выводил бы двойным запросом.

В вашем случае вывод делается цикл в цикле, то есть сначала вы берете пользователя, а потом выводите его оценки.